# Is there any way to erase personal information from my phone that has already been stolen?

Tags: security, lost-phone, privacy

My phone has been stolen. I do not want the thief to have access to any of my personal information such as calls, texts, and information saved in the phones contents. Is there any possible way I can get this information erased from my phone?

Comment: Sorry to hear about your phone being stolen. If you can get PlanB set up on it and locate your phone, be careful with the action you take against the thief.

Answer (score 20):

As long as your phone still has battery power left and is still switched on and connected to the phone networks, you can use one of the phone wiping apps that specifically advertise that they can be remotely installed and used after the phone is stolen.

From a quick search of the Android Market, there are [PlanB](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb) that is designed for this purpose:

> Plan B is the 'find my phone' app that
>   you download AFTER you lose your
>   phone.
>
> Plan B is your last resort to find
>   your missing phone.
>
> This is the first and only 'find my
>   phone' app that you download AFTER
>   you've already lost your phone. Having
>   Lookout on your phone is the best way
>   to protect your phone and find it
>   fast, but use Plan B if you have
>   already lost your phone and didn't
>   have Lookout installed.

And [Phonelocator Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rvo.plpro) is one that advertises this:

> - Can be installed after the phone was lost. Install this application to your
>     phone from the web Android Market
>     remotely. Send the "PLlocator" word to
>     your phone, in a text message. It will
>     respond back with the phone position.
>     The word is case sensitive, so be sure
>     you send this exact word "PLlocator"

Comment: Wow, very cool use of the Market's push feature.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you installed an app to do this (obviously not in your case) or if your phone came with such functionality.  If you don't know if you have it or don't know how to use it, you should call your carrier and ask.  They will know best what to do about a stolen phone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to google dashboard
and click wipe when you find the device in it

https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard

Answer (score 0):

If your devices didn't stole but you want to protect your device.

You may need to install the [Google Device Manger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm&hl=en)

And go to [DeviceManager](https://www.google.co.th/android/devicemanager)

[image]