# My phone was just stolen an hour or so ago. Are there any options for tracking?

Tags: security, lost-phone

I realize this is a long shot, but my phone was lost or stolen a few hours ago.

At the time it was stolen, I didn't have any specific applications installed to track it or wipe the data. So... my bad. I'm hoping the fact that I have a pattern lock will at least prevent anyone from accessing my data.

My question is, do I have any options for tracking or data wipe after the fact? (I'm more interested in tracking.)

Note: I have read similar questions, but unless I'm mistaken, they all address the question in terms of preparation before losing the phone. I'm asking about fallback options *after* losing the phone.

Comment: See also  [Is there any way to erase personal information from my phone that has already been stolen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9101/) which covers phone tracking as well as wiping

Comment: I strongly recommend you change your Google account password.  Like, now.

Comment: it's not just changing account passwords... you have to explicitly un-associate the device from certain accounts. Dropbox is one such, as is twitter

Comment: If you have changed your password before remotely installing Plan B, I doubt that, Plan B can get installed remotely, because of authentication failure.

Comment: @iSid: Good point to note, though in this case I did install and attempt to execute Plan B before changing my Google password.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can install [Plan B](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5sb29rb3V0LmxhYnMucGxhbmIiXQ..) remotely to your phone via the Market's web interface. Plan B was made exactly for this, to get the location of your phone AFTER it has been stolen.

Comment: Is there an alternative that works on a Galaxy Pad Galaxy Tab 10.1v GT-P7100?

Comment: Ah I see: [Android Lost](http://www.androidlost.com)

Comment: Unfortunately Plan B only works with 2.0 - 2.3 versions of Android.

Answer (score 5):

[Android Lost](http://www.androidlost.com) is another app that you can install **after** your phone has been stolen.

Quote from the link:

> **No pre installation required**
>   You didn't install AndroidLost on your
>   phone? No problem! You can push the AndroidLost app to your phone from
>   google market and initiate the connection to googles servers by
>   sending an SMS with the message "androidlost register" to your phone.

Comment: As of 2014 and possibly some version of Android I don't think that is possible now because of the need to send an SMS or register the phone by starting the application (which the person in possession of the phone would need to do) - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/androidlost/Vo5_F0wF_do/0CUPZ5o2nuYJ

Answer (score 3):

Same situation here. However if you changed your account's password before installing Plan B and your phone was off, you still have a chance to get that app installed and trace it, at least it worked for me after changing it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised that no-one has suggested going to the play store / device manager and using the built-in tools for locking and erasing the device in question. Go here: https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager?hl=en&u=0

Answer (score 2):

Whoever stole it probably turned it off. You should probably call your carrier if you know the IMEI.