# Get my samsung password without reset it for my stolen android device

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-apps

My galaxcy s2 is stolen and i need to track it using my samsung account but i dont remember the pass; Can anyone please tell me how could i know my samsung account password without resting it as used in samsung account SignIn procedure to find password by email

Answer (score 3):

Unless Samsung are complete muppets, even they don't know your password: all they know is a special *hashed* form of the password, which is an irreversible function a bit like encrypting it. When you type in your password, they *hash* what you type in in the same way, and then compare the two hashed passwords. This way, they can check your password without knowing what it is.

For this reason, there shouldn't be any way to find out what your password is without first changing it. If that turns out not to be true, it would be a very embarrassing security problem for Samsung.

If you want to find a lost or stolen phone, there are other options that don't involve your Samsung account. See the answers to [My phone was just stolen an hour or so ago. Are there any options for tracking?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/18644/12442) for some alternatives that you can install remotely via Google Play.