# Mobile Lost and some one else is using the mobile with a different sim

Tags: security, external-sd, lost-phone, remote-access

I need help to track the person who has my mobile.

My account(email) is still linked with google play on that mobile.
I can install apps from my browser from google play account.

Is there any app that I can install from google play and find the location/sim number from my browser.

Or

Erase SD memory card from browse.

Comment: You should check out the questions tagged [lost-phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-phone), which already has a lot of questions and answers to this problem, like [My phone was just stolen an hour or so ago. Are there any options for tracking?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18644)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) if your phone is linked to your Google account. It can track down your phone but you may not be able to erase the contents due to you need to allow that beforehand.

Comment: Doesn't tracking itself already needs to be enabled on the device? Besides, ADM never found any of my devices, though I even enabled it in the device's *device manager* section...