# Cracked screen, menu buttons non-responsive, need to wipe my phone! Ideas? HELP!

Tags: screen, factory-reset, buttons

Like so many of us, I have dropped my phone and cracked the screen on my LG optimus ls970... which, In my very special situation, makes the menu buttons stop working. However, unlike other posters, I can still SEE the screen. I even managed to somehow (and I have NO idea how) to get into the boot options. But I CAN'T CLICK THE OPTION TO WIPE THE PHONE OR CONFIRM. I can press my glass at a million angles and make the equivalent of a pretty, pretty light show, but the only portion of my screen that ever responds to touch now is the top-right corner.

I work for a security company and have customer-sensitive information on that device. I too have already received a replacement and need to send the old device back. ...I even have an old microwave and have SERIOUSLY considered both using it and "dropping" the phone in a lake before I send it back (as it is covered for water damage), but I have seen phones recover even from water damage. I have NO idea how I'm going to solve this. ...Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The answers to [Is there any way to erase personal information from my phone that has already been stolen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9101/is-there-any-way-to-erase-personal-information-from-my-phone-that-has-already-be) might help you here. Although your phone hasn't been stolen, the same solution seems like it would be appropriate to your case.

If you have sensitive information on your device, and your company doesn't already have a way to remote-wipe it, then what you work for is an *in*-security company. You should figure out what to do about lost or stolen devices before it happens. Right now, you're putting your customers at risk.

Comment: Agreed with the last part. You should get someone to make an app that can remotely wipe the device.

Comment: Yes, but guess what? Thats done via an app and device management.

Comment: No, someone hasn't already made an app. They would need to get someone to make an app that implemented the device management features on Android so as to use them. There isn't an app already made for the company that uses the specific device management commands they would need, or even the remote interface they would need.

Comment: And that assumes that the company uses google apps, which is unlikely? I'll transfer this to chat and continue in the morning...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8044/discussion-between-liam-w-and-dan-hulme)

Comment: Missed the chat session, I suppose.  

Whom I work for would surprise you, Dan.  Suffice it to say if we hadn't been purchased twice in the last two years, this would not have occurred, but as we are in procedural limbo... well, it doesn't really matter at the moment, because it won't resolve my problem.

I know I can't ssh into the appliance.  I tried downloading the SDK, but it will only get me as far as I have already gotten before the hard buttons are needed.  I have volume and power functional, but that's it.  No enter/menu button.  ...It's not a pleasant situation to be in.