# Can't add Samsungdive Account

Tags: samsung-galaxy-mini

My Mobile device is "Galaxy s5570-mini", I want to secure it if it's lost -God forbidden- so I signed up in Samsungdive.com with my Gmail account then I have to add "Setting>Accounts and Sync>Add account>samsung account" in my mobile but I can't find this option !! what's wrong?? any thing is missed ?

Answer (score 2):

Samsungdive.com has nothing to with the "Accounts and Sync" options. Samsung Dive consists of a background App (called *uTrack*), an Website (samsungdive.com) and an Login/Password, which allows you to *remotely locate, lock and/or wipe* **some** Samsung devices.

To pair your device with the Samsung DIVE, enter your login data under

```
Settings -> Location and Security -> uTrack
```

(Not sure if this is true for the Galaxy Mini, but that's where the setting is on the SGS)

Comment: Thanks Mr.Flow for your help :), but still can't find a way since two days of searching :'(....I can't find the option you mentioned.Then should I use an app would do the same ?

Comment: Well, not every Samsung device has uTrack/DIVE support. I am not sure about the Galaxy Mini. But there are alternatives in the market. [See this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12608/is-there-a-way-to-block-access-to-or-wipe-my-google-data-for-a-lost-stolen-phone)

Comment: But as you notice they described that it's available for these devices included mine :("http://v2.samsungdive.com/help/guideRemoteControlsClear.do#"

Comment: FYI on my SGS (UK Gingerbread) it's under **Settings** -> **Location and Security** -> **Mobile Tracker** unfortunately I'm pretty sure that it's also possible that your network, or or your regional Samsung may not distribute it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried entering a password into the mobile tracker.

When I did this, the window came up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to get it working Cerberus would be a very good alternative.

I use it, and it is flawless.