# Stolen phone: is changing your GMail password enough?

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s, security, lost-phone, google-account

My Galaxy phone got stolen today. Of course I blocked my SIM card and changed my password for GMail (and went to the police) but is this enough?  Could the person that stole my phone still log in to my market and download stuff?  Not sure what the deal is for that and I'm really freaking out about how much this person could possibly do with my phone.

Also about the payment: I never bought any apps (I only downloaded free ones).  How does this payment work? Is that also blocked if your SIM card is blocked?

And is there a way to delete "My Market" account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to block access to or wipe my Google data for a lost/stolen phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12608/is-there-a-way-to-block-access-to-or-wipe-my-google-data-for-a-lost-stolen-phone)

Comment: You should also look into setting up 2-factor authentication. With this you control what accesses your Google accounts (computers, devices, websites) and can revoke access with a click of a link. http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1056283

Answer (score 4):

You should check out Lookout's [Plan B app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5sb29rb3V0LmxhYnMucGxhbmIiXQ..). It lets you find your phone after it is lost.

I would recommend using [Seekdroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.gtmedia.seekdroid.lite&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5ndG1lZGlhLnNlZWtkcm9pZC5saXRlIl0.) or [Where's my Droid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alienmanfc6.wheresmyandroid&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbGllbm1hbmZjNi53aGVyZXNteWFuZHJvaWQiXQ..) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing the password, you should go to the market on the web and "deactivate the device."

Comment: There has never been any way to do this on the Market's website. You can hide devices from the menus but you cannot remove them from your account unless this has changed *very* recently.