# Protecting Android Phone

Tags: hardware

Is there a way like how Apple has icloud but for Android where if you lose your phone someone is not able to wipe it and then resell/reuse it?

And does Android also have builtin tracking like how iCloud does too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Find my iPhone" for Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23969/find-my-iphone-for-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does have similar tracking/security features that you can access remotely if you lose your phone. They call it `Android Device Manager`. I do not know which Android phones have this built in. If it is not built in to your phone, you can download the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm&hl=en).

To locate your phone, simply visit this [link](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) and log into your Google account.

I know that the application supports:

- Locate Android devices associated with your Google account
- Reset/Enable your device's screen lock PIN
- Erase all data on the phone
- Ring the phone for 5 minutes if you've misplaced it

Comment: I'm fairly sure that Android Device Manager is built into almost every newer (jellybean and up) android phone.